# Celery beat with method tasks not working

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to run celerybeat on a method task, and can't get anything to work out properly. Here's an example setup:

```
from celery.contrib.methods import task_method
from celery import Celery, current_app

celery=celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
celery.config_from_object("celeryconfig")
class X(object):
    @celery.task(filter=task_method, name="X.ppp")
    def ppp(self):
        print "ppp"
```

and my celeryconfig.py file is

```
from datetime import timedelta
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
      'test' : {
               'task' : 'X.ppp', 
               'schedule' : timedelta(seconds=5)
               }, 
 }
```

When I run `celery beat`, I'm getting errors like:

```
 task X.ppp raised exception, TypeError('ppp() takes exactly 1 argument, (0 given)
```

When I turn the method into a normal function and decorate it with `@celery.task', it does work, so the rest of the setup seems to be working. I see the caveats [in the docs about method tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html), but can't really sort out where the problem is. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it using class methods instead of using functions in python modules? I have the same exact situation, but my application is heavily implemented in classes, so I can't make it functions now .. can you help on this?

Comment: I never found an answer to it at the time, but I haven't been looking for one either. If you find a good solution, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Celerybeat will not instantiate X before calling the method.  The task_method filter defaults to calling the unbound method if the method is not bound to an object.

My question is, what are you trying to accomplish here?  X has no state, so why not use a module-evel function?

Comment: This is just an example that reproduces the same effect of the real objects/tasks that I am doing. Is there some way to do this with celerybeat?

Comment: There may be.  But I'm still unclear about what you're trying to do.  Do you have an instance of the class that you want Celerybeat to invoke the task against?  If so, how is Celerybeat to know the instance you would like to invoke the task against?

Comment: Nope, no object is instantiated. Just the classes in tasks.py

Comment: Then Celery (by way of Celerybeat) has no object to invoke the task against.

Comment: Perhaps.  Though it may help you to understand exactly what's happening: 'filter_method' literally wraps the task method in a descriptor -- when Celery accesses the task it will bind the task to the instance it's invoked against, and if no instance is present, it executes the task unbound

Comment: Interesting, there may be some workarounds for my setup, else, I'll convert stuff over to @task decorated functions