# Celery Beat: How to define periodic tasks defined as classes (class based tasks)

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

Till now I had only worked with Celery tasks defined as functions. I used to define their periodicity in the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` parameter. Like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

Now I am trying to use class-based tasks, like this one:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    """My Task."""

    def run(self, source, *args, **kwargs):
        """Run the celery task."""
        logger.info("Hi!")
```

My question is: how do I define the periodic execution of class-based tasks?

Comment: Not sure if this is supported. Please read the comments of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515331/126125. Basically, Celerybeat will not instantiate the object - it needs a callback. According to the official documentation (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries), you need to specify a Task name. Why are you using a class and not a normal function?

Comment: No answer to this, and no mentioning in the docs