# Celery class based tasks with CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE

Tags: django, celery, class-based-tasks

I am wondering what is the correct approach here, and cannot find any data about this while googling:

Assuming I have the class:

```
class OkPayPaymentChecker(BasePaymentChecker):
    pass
```

in 'nexchnage/tasks.py'

what would be the correct `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` entry for this task?

is it:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'check_okpay_payments': {
        'task': 'nexchange.tasks.OkPayPaymentChecker',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60),
    },
}
```

Or should create an instance with it first?

Unanswered related questions:

[Celery beat with method tasks not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515218/celery-beat-with-method-tasks-not-working/14515331#14515331)

[Celery Beat: How to define periodic tasks defined as classes (class based tasks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924442/celery-beat-how-to-define-periodic-tasks-defined-as-classes-class-based-tasks)